# angular2 nested components

Tags: typescript, components, angular

I have multiple components, each one has its own view template  *(angular2 alpha 46)*

- PostCmp
- CommentCmp
- ShareCmp

I want to load them from a main component and display them in its own view template

- SingleCmp

I will start by loading one component "PostCmp" through "SingleCmp"

**PostCmp:**

```js
import { Component, Injectable, CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';
import { WPService } from './../../lib/wpservice';
import { Post } from './../../lib/PostType';

@Component({
 selector: 'post',
 viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, WPService],
 templateUrl: './app/shared/post/post.html',
 directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class PostCmp {
 post: Post;
 constructor(id: string, service: WPService) {
  //this.post = new Post(params.get('id'), service); original
      this.post = new Post(id, service);
 }
}
```

```html
<h1 [inner-html]="post.title"></h1>
<div *ng-if="post.featured_image_url!==''" class="post-thumbnail">
 <img width="250" height="auto" [src]="post.featured_image_url" />
</div>
<div class="post-date">
 {{post.date}}
</div>
<div class="post-content" [inner-html]="post.content"></div>
</div>
```

*the component above is tested and its working.*

**SingleCmp:**

```js
import { Component, Injectable, CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';
import { WPService } from './../../lib/wpservice';


import { PostCmp } from './../../shared/post/post';

@Component({
 selector: 'single',
 viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, WPService, PostCmp],
 templateUrl: './app/components/single/single.html',
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SingleCmp {
    //how can I display PostCmp from SingleCmp template??
 post: PostCmp;
 constructor(params: RouteParams, service: WPService) {
  post = new PostCmp(params.get('id'), service);
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- something like this -->
{{post}}

<!--{{share}}-->
<!--{{comment}}-->
```

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SinglCmp should look like this

```
<SinglCmp>
  <PostCmp></PostCmp>
  <ShareCmp></ShareCmp>
  <CommentCmp></CommentCmp>
</SinglCmp>
```

Be sure to correctly import components in your SinglCmp component and also add directives.